# Vector Dot / Cross Product for Lane Monitoring

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I am developing an application which is monitoring the speed of the vehicle with the help of mapkit and CoreLocation Frameworks in Xcode. But I also have to monitor the lane tracking as in identify if the vehicle is going in the same lane, or how frequently is the driver changing the lanes. And if he's changing too frequently , I have to pop an alert saying be alert.
When the driver turns right, a message has to pop up saying "Turned Right" and similarly when turns left, a message has to pop up saying "Turned Left".
I am only allowed to usa the GPS Coordinates and nothing else.

How am i supposed to approach this problem? How can I use Vector DOT / CROSS Product for solving this ?
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks !!

Comment: Only *allowed* to use GPS coordinates?  You can't use the location.course? or the compass heading? what about the horizontalAccuracy and headingAccuracy?  First, you must make sure you have an accurate GPS signal and compass heading before you can do anything with them.

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure that the GPS is accurate enough for your project. I don't have a lot of experience with the GPS capabilities, but I don't believe that they are accurate enough to detect lane changes. The only GPSs that I know of that are accurate enough for this are on prototype buses that can drive on the road shoulder based off of GPS. Anyway, if the iPhone GPS suits your needs, you should look into linear algebra and matrix operations to deal with vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this with positional vectors is possible by first turning them into velocity and acceleration vectors. If time is constant here (sampling rate is fixed and regular) it can be ignored and the conversion from position to velocity can be made by simple subtraction.

```
velX[i] = posX[i+1] - posX[i];
velY[i] = posY[i+1] - posY[i];

accX[i] = velX[i+1] - velX[i];
accY[i] = velY[i+1] - velY[i];
```

Now we have x,y vectors for velocity and for acceleration at a bunch of different times (i).  What you want is the part of the acceleration vector that is perpendicular to the velocity vector.

**A · V** / **|V|** Would project the acceleration vector onto velocity vector.  Exactly 90 degrees from what we want.  That's wrong but maybe we can use this idea.

A right rotated vector perpendicular to ⟨a,b⟩ is ⟨b,-a⟩.

So we could find a right rotated vector perpendicular to **V** just by swapping the numbers and negating.  Lets call that **Vp**.

ap = **A · Vp** / **|Vp|** would project the acceleration vector onto a vector pointing out the right side of the car (unless they're driving backwards or skidding).  Yeah that's what we want.  + means accelerating to the right.  - means accelerating to the left.

**|Vp|** might be a tad expensive to calculate since it involves a square root (Pythagorean theorem) but this is really just the same as **|V|**, the speed of the vehicle relative to the time between data samples.  If you're tracking the speed you likely already calculated it somewhere else.

That works if all you need is a scalar for the sideways acceleration.  If you need the actual vector calculate the unit vector out the right side **Vp**/ **|Vp|** and scale it by ap.

**Ap** = ap (**Vp**/ **|Vp|**)

The problem with all this is it completely ignores the map.  Having a left or right acceleration doesn't necessarily indicate a lane change if the map indicates the road is turning.

So you also have to have data points that indicate the path they were supposed to take.  Apply the measured speed to the path data points and predict what the perpendicular acceleration should have been.  The math for that is much the same as I've already covered.  The difference between predicted and measured is the lane change.

However, even if they drive a perfect path those map data points most likely wont match up exactly with your positional data points because of timing.  So you'd have to do some interpolation to predict what the perpendicular acceleration should have been at the samples time.

As you can see the answer involves a lot of math.  Maybe you should follow up on [mathmatics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).